# Telugu Text is not displaying in itext pdf Java

Tags: java, spring, itext

I am creating an application using Java and Spring Boot, I am Generating a pdf Using itext Library. This pdf has both Telugu and English Languages. but, The problem is English is appearing Properly in the PDF but coming to Telugu Language I am getting Blank instead of Telugu text.

I've included **Character.UnicodeScript.TELUGU** and **BaseFont.IDENTITY_H**

But nothing works. So, anyone Please guide me to solve this issue. Thank You.

Below I am Attching the Code Please, check.

1. Code

public class PdfTelugu {

```
public void export(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, School school)    
                throws DocumentException, ParseException, java.io.IOException
{
    

    //Create Document
    Document doc  = new Document();
    
    //Pass 2 things ---> What to render & where to render
    PdfWriter instance2 = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, response.getOutputStream());

    //Open the document to start the work
    doc.open();

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
    table.setWidthPercentage(100.0f);

    table.setWidths(new float[] {1.5f, 11.6f, 10.0f });
    Paragraph heading = new Paragraph();

    //Testing for Telugu Text

    Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.defaultEncoding, 11, Font.NORMAL);

                PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("1", font));
                c1.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                c1.setPaddingBottom(12f);
                //c1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
                table.addCell(c1);

                c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("పాఠశాల పేరు", font));
                c1.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                c1.setPaddingBottom(12f);
                //c1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);            
                table.addCell(c1);

                c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("School Name",  font));
                c1.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                c1.setPaddingBottom(12f);
                //c1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);        
                table.addCell(c1);  

            //Here, Closing the document.
            doc.close();
            try {
                ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
                os.flush();
                os.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

My be this won't solve your problem but it will help you to diagnose it. Your problem may be caused by multiple causes. Two major ones are:

1. The Telugu text gets corrupted before it gets passed to iText library;
2. your computer may not have Telugu true type font installed so iText library doesn't know what to print in. (or some other problem related to iText library)

So, in order to find out which one try to pass Unicodes sequence representing your Telugu text instead of actual Telugu text. In your example replace the line:

```
c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("పాఠశాల పేరు", font));
```

with:

```
c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("\\u0c2a\\u0c3e\\u0c20\\u0c36\\u0c3e\\u0c32\\u0020\\u0c2a\\u0c47\\u0c30\\u0c41", font));
```

Just to make it clear The Unicode sequence That represents string `"పాఠశాల పేరు"` is `\u0c2a\u0c3e\u0c20\u0c36\u0c3e\u0c32\u0020\u0c2a\u0c47\u0c30\u0c41` If the problem still persists than it points out that your text was passed correctly and iText library has a problem writing it properly into PDF. When I encountered problem like this I found that I didn't have needed true type font installed on my computer. However, if passing Unicode sequence solves your problem, it means that your Telugu text got corrupted before it was passed to iText library.
There are a lot of ways to convert any text into Unicode sequence. I used my own util that does it. If you interested - youcan use Open Source java library MgntUtils written and maintained by me that has a Utility that converts Strings to unicode sequence and vise versa:

```
result = "Hello World";
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(result);
System.out.println(result);
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

The output of this code is:

```
\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064
Hello World
```

The library can be found at [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.2/jar) or at [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) It comes as maven artifact and with sources and javadoc

Here is javadoc for the class [StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html)

Comment: Thank you for responding to me. the unicode text is displaying as it is. it is not converting into the telugu text. I've also added "com.github.michaelgantman" dependency. but it is not working.

Comment: Try replacing in the string '\\' with just '\' and that should do the trick. As for mgnt utils dependency not working what exactly not working? This library is in use by other people and it works fine.

Comment: when I replaced with single slash then it is displaying as empty in pdf like same happened to telugu text. so, it is not taking proper telugu text and unicode of telugu text

Comment: So, this means that your problem is in the library itself. If I had to guess I'd say that you don't have appropriate true type font installed on your computer